Exercise on Poisson processes
Let $(N^k)_{k\in Q}$ be a countable family of homogeneus Poisson processes with respective intensities $(\lambda_k)_{k \in Q}$. Assume $\lambda = \sum_{k \in Q}\lambda_k < \infty$.
Let $T_1$ denote the first arrival time of the process $N_t = \sum_{k \in Q}N_t^k$, $t \ge 0$, and let $I$ be the index of the process responsible for it, namely such that $T_1 = T_1^I$, where $T_1^k$ is the first arrival time of the process $N^k$.
Prove that $I$ and $T_1$ are independent, and derive the density of $I$ on $Q$.
I have tried to solve this exercise in the following way:
using the fact that $T_1^k$ has exponential distribution with parameter $\lambda_k$,we have:
$P( I = k$,$ T_1 \ge t) = P( T_1^k \ge t$,$T_1^j > T_1^k\forall j \neq k)$ $ = \int_{t}^{+\infty}\lambda_ke^{-\lambda_ks}P(T_1^j > s \forall j \neq k)ds = \int_{t}^{+\infty}\lambda_ke^{-\lambda_ks}\prod_{j \neq k}e^{-\lambda_js}ds = \int_{t}^{+\infty}\lambda_ke^{-\lambda s}ds = \frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda}e^{-\lambda t} $.
This show the independence between $I$ and $T_1$; moreover we have that
$P(I = k) = \frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda}, \forall k \in Q$
Is this approach correct or I have made some mistakes?
EDIT (after @Michael comment):
To show $P(I = k) = \frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda}, \forall k \in Q$ I proceed as follow:\
$P(I = k) = P(T_1^k = min(T_1^1, T_1^2, ...)) = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\lambda_ke^{-\lambda_kx}P(T_1^k = min(T_1^1, T_1^2, ... | T_1^k = x)dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\lambda_ke^{-\lambda_kx}\prod_{j \neq k}e^{-\lambda_jx}dx = \int_{0}^{+\infty}\lambda_ke^{-\lambda x} = \frac{\lambda_k}{\lambda}$

The Poisson processes need to be mutually independent for this to be true.

Assuming independence, your work is correct but you need to obtain the marginal distributions at the end so that you can show you have a product form for independence.

I have edited the answer, can you check if it is correct? @Michael

Assuming independence, that is correct, but you are doing too much work: You already have $P[I=k, T\geq t]$ for all $k \in Q$ and $t\geq 0$. So you can get the marginal distributions $P[I=k]$ and $P[T\geq t]$ (for all $k\in Q$, $t\geq 0$) directly from that, similar to how you integrate out a joint density to get a marginal density, or how you get a marginal CDF from a joint CDF: For each $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have $$P[X\leq x] = \lim_{y\rightarrow\infty} P[X\leq x, Y\leq y]$$ [Minor comment: It would be good to use phrases like "Fix $k \in Q, t\geq 0$" before your derivations.]

So to get the marginal distribution P[I = k] it is enough to consider the expression I have derived for P[I=k,T≥t] and take t = 0? Since  P[I = k] = P[I=k,T≥0] @Michael

Yes. You can see that is consistent with your other calculation for $P[I=k]$. You can also get $P[T\geq t]$, then you can verify the product form
